# Booting issue after wrong cmd command

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I took a leap of faith and installed Ubuntu on a dual partions with windows 10 on a Dell XPS.

Ubuntu worked great, and could select to boot it or windows at start up.

Until I booted windows again a few days later, after every restart, the computer would straight away boot into windows10 not giving me choice anymore.

Chasing the problem I came across this command on one of the thread that could potentially solve my issue.

"bcdedit /set {bootmgr} \EF"

since, I am now facing a "No bootable devices found" on start up.

-I do not have a choice in boot sequence via Bios.

-Tried "enable secure boot" with no success.

I am a complete novice and looking for a way to at least boot one of the OS. Any help appreciated.

Greatings

Q

Comment: You have typo in command, corrupting the Windows BCD. That will require you to use your Windows repair disk & create new BCD. Can you boot Ubuntu from UEFI boot menu? Often f12, but varies by brand. Should be same key you used to boot live installer, but now have "ubuntu" entry or a drive entry that is a fallback boot.

Comment: Thank's for lighting up the issue. So pointless to try booting windows. I do not seem to have the option to boot Ubuntu in the bios. Not sure if this is relevant but During the install I selected the "windows boot manager" as my Device for "boot loader installation". Is it possible to boot Ubuntu via USB to get access to my hard drive?

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/  You never install grub boot loader to a partition like sda1, but only to a drive like sda. If UEFI, it automatically knows to install into the ESP - efi system partition. If you actually installed grub to Windows partition that may also have corrupted Windows.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7mvg9bv2fV/

Comment: You have bitlocker on. Not sure how to repair a encrypted Windows. This is an Ubuntu question & answer site. You also have UEFI installs, but booted live installer in old BIOS boot mode. Only boot in UEFI mode as the mode you boot repair or install flash drives is the mode it repairs. And you definitely do not want to make BIOS repairs as that further corrupts system. Not sure if bitlocker also locked ESP, so that is why you cannot boot Ubuntu. You should then be able to boot Ubuntu from external drive. Manual boot, chroot or SuperGrub are ways to boot. But use UEFI only.